# ES6 module: not working inside html file even when attached to Window.prototype, why?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

Defined a function as ES6 module, in an external JS file imported in `index.html` inside a `type=module`, since `import/export` can only be used inside modules and then set it on global `Window.prototype` so that its' accessible to the code scope of the second `script` tag, however its not working.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Simple html document.</p>

        <script type="module">
            import { showPlayerName } from './test.js'
            Window.prototype.showPlayerName = showPlayerName;
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">         
            showPlayerName();
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**test.js**

```
export function showPlayerName(){
    return 'Leo Messi'; 
}
```

`Error: index.html: Uncaught ReferenceError: showPlayerName is not defined`

If the function is called inside the `<script type="module"></script>` that does not even run, Why

Can someone let me know why calling inside `type=module` and `window.showPlayerName` in non `type="module"` wont work.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Module scripts do not run immediately when the engine comes across their `<script>` tag in the HTML:

```html
<p>Simple html document.</p>

<script type="module">
  console.log('module running');
  window.showPlayerName = () => console.log('foo');
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  showPlayerName();
</script>
```

So `showPlayerName` is not defined at the time you try to call it from a non-module script.

While there are ways to get around this by waiting for the module script you're interested in to load, the better approach is, if you have any module scripts, to put *everything* into modules so that it becomes a non-issue.

```
<script type="module">
  import { showPlayerName } from './test.js'
  showPlayerName();
</script>
```

This also has the advantage of not requiring the creation of any global variables.